# SQL query showing incorrect results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access and I have this SQL query which does all the relevant joins:

```
SELECT c.ID
FROM   ((((((((Cars c
               INNER JOIN Offers
                       ON c.ID = Offers.car_id)
              INNER JOIN Users u
                      ON c.owner_id = u.ID)
             INNER JOIN City
                     ON u.city_id = City.ID)
            INNER JOIN Models
                    ON c.model_id = Models.ID)
           INNER JOIN Makes
                   ON Models.make_id = Makes.ID)
          INNER JOIN Type
                  ON Models.type_id = Type.ID) ))
WHERE  ( Offers.decision <> 3 )
```

In my Cars table I have 1 car and in my offers table I have 3 offers for the same car which have a Offers.decision of 2 and 4, for some reason when I execute the query it shows the same car 3 times like it is going on the basis of 3 offers.

Is their a way to show cars that do not have an Offers.decision of 3?

Comment: Change your select statement to return each of the related IDs, look for what you're not expecting; that'll give you the clue to the issue which you need to solve this.  From what's shown above there's no obvious issue in the code.

Comment: Can you post the relevant schema and some sample data?  Consider setting up a SQL fiddle that demonstrates the problem [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a join but a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT car_id FROM Offers WHERE decision <> 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your query to just:

```
SELECT        c.ID
FROM            Cars c INNER JOIN
                     Offers ON c.ID = Offers.car_id
```

WHERE (Offers.decision <> 3)